# Exploring file with tail command

Tags: linux, unix

I'm using tail -f  for watching log files in "real time". 
What to do so be able to view only lines containig 127.0.0.1 for example  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep` is your friend:

```
 tail -f foo | grep '127\.0\.0\.1'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tail -f /path/to/log/file | grep --line-buffered 127.0.0.1
```

The `--line-buffered` is not strictly needed for `grep(1)` in this case, but it would be if you wanted to send output to `less(1)` or some further processing steps, and still wanted to see individual lines as they were logged. (See `setvbuf(3)` for full details on the buffering.)

Answer (score 2):

Watch is also a cool command for this

watch grep '127.0.0.1' foo

and it will update every 2 seconds.

Comment: +1. However, the runtime requirements are very different - watch will re-run grep on the whole file every two seconds, while tail will only output new lines to be scanned once.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to grep all the lines containing any IP address and not only 127.0.0.1 then

```
tail -f filename|grep '^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}$'
```